# My new div element is not appearing in the webpage. It seems, the div element is hidden behind the background image

Tags: html, css

My new div element (`<div id="secondary-content">`) seems to be hidden behind the image. Anything, I type is displaying behind the image. I would like to continue working after the background image.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">

<head>
  <title>DISPLAY</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <header>
      <div class="logo">
        <h1 class="title ir"></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="navigation">
        <div>
          <a href="#" class="twitter"></a>
          <a href="#" class="facebook"></a>
          <a href="#" class="blog"></a>
          <a href="#" class="pin"></a>
          <a href="#" class="google"></a>
          <a href="#" class="inter"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="header bottom">
    <hr>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">ABOUT</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="company">Company</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="text1">Text1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="text1">Text1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="text1">Text1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="text1">Text1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="banner">
      <img src="img/bg.jpg" />
      <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et has omnium luptatum, eos ad simul discere honestatis. Ius laudem commodo conceptam eu, sit no dico altera.
        </p>
      </div>
      <p id="submission">
        <button class="button">Browse Portfolio</button>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="secondary-content">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <article style="background-image: url('images/article-image-1.jpg');">
        <div class="overlay">
          <h4>Secondary Content</h4>
          <p><small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec euismod leo a nibh dignissim tincidunt nam.</small></p>
          <a href="#" class="more-link">View more</a>
        </div>
      </article>
      <article style="background-image: url('images/article-image-2.jpg');">
        <div class="overlay">
          <h4>Secondary Content</h4>
          <p><small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec euismod leo a nibh dignissim tincidunt nam.</small></p>
          <a href="#" class="more-link">View more</a>
        </div>
      </article>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the css code is here

```
* {
  padding: 0 px;
  margin: 0 px;
}

body {
  font - family: 'Roboto', sans - serif;
  font - size: 18 px;
}


/* logo */

.ir {
  background - color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text - indent: -9999 px;
  background - image: url(img / logo.jpg);
  background - size: 100 % auto;
  background - repeat: no - repeat;
  width: 100 %;
  height: 100 %;
}

.header {
  height: 140 px;
}

.logo {
  width: 18 %;
  float: left;
  height: 100 %;
}

.logo h1 {
  display: inline - block;
  margin - left: 100 %;
  margin - top: 10 %;
}

.navigation {
  float: right;
  width: 43 %;
  margin - top: 4 %;
}


/* social icons */

.facebook {
  height: 50 px;
  width: 50 px;
  font - size: 0 px;
  display: inline - block;
  background - image: url("img/icons/facebook.png");
  background - repeat: no - repeat;
}

.facebook: hover {
  background - image: url("img/icons/facebookc.png");
  height: 50 px;
  width: 50 px;
  font - size: 0 px;
  display: inline - block;
  background - repeat: no - repeat;
}

.twitter {
  height: 50 px;
  width: 50 px;
  font - size: 0 px;
  display: inline - block;
  background - image: url("img/icons/twitter.png");
  background - repeat: no - repeat;
}

.twitter: hover {
  background - image: url("img/icons/twitterc.png");
  height: 50 px;
  width: 50 px;
  font - size: 0 px;
  display: inline - block;
  background - repeat: no - repeat;
}

.blog {
  height: 50 px;
  width: 50 px;
  font - size: 0 px;
  display: inline - block;
  background - image: url("img/icons/blog.png");
  background - repeat: no - repeat;
}

.blog: hover {
  background - image: url("img/icons/blogc.png");
  height: 50 px;
  width: 50 px;
  font - size: 0 px;
  display: inline - block;
  background - repeat: no - repeat;
}

.pin {
  height: 50 px;
  width: 50 px;
  font - size: 0 px;
  display: inline - block;
  background - image: url("img/icons/pininterest.png");
  background - repeat: no - repeat;
}

.pin: hover {
  background - image: url("img/icons/pininterestc.png");
  height: 50 px;
  width: 50 px;
  font - size: 0 px;
  display: inline - block;
  background - repeat: no - repeat;
}

.google {
  height: 50 px;
  width: 50 px;
  font - size: 0 px;
  display: inline - block;
  background - image: url("img/icons/google.png");
  background - repeat: no - repeat;
}

.google: hover {
  background - image: url("img/icons/googlec.png");
  height: 50 px;
  width: 50 px;
  font - size: 0 px;
  display: inline - block;
  background - repeat: no - repeat;
}

.inter {
  height: 50 px;
  width: 50 px;
  font - size: 0 px;
  display: inline - block;
  background - image: url("img/icons/spider.png");
  background - repeat: no - repeat;
}

.inter: hover {
  background - image: url("img/icons/spiderc.png");
  height: 50 px;
  width: 50 px;
  font - size: 0 px;
  display: inline - block;
  background - repeat: no - repeat;
}

header {
  float: left;
  width: 100 %;
  height: 140 px;
  background - color: light - grey;
}

hr {
  display: block;
  margin - top: 0.5e m;
  margin - bottom: 0.5e m;
  margin - left: 19 %;
  margin - right: 20 %;
  border - style: inset;
  border - width: 1 px;
}

.menu,
.menu ul,
.menu li,
.menu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

ul.menu {
  margin: 1 % auto 0 18 %;
}

.menu {
  height: 40 px;
  width: 350 px;
  background: #FFF;
  /* change it to #FFF */
}

.menu li {
  list - style: none;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  height: 40 px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu li a {
  display: block;
  text - decoration: none;
  font - weight: bold;
  color: #737373;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  transition: color .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: color .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .3s ease;
}

.menu li:hover > a {
  color: #2ECD71;
}


/* submenu */

.menu ul {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: #BABABA;
  transition: opacity.25 s ease.1 s;
  - moz - transition: opacity.25 s ease.1 s;
  - webkit - transition: opacity.25 s ease.1 s;
  - ms - transition: opacity.25 s ease.1 s;
}

.menu li: hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu ul li {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu li: hover > ul li {
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}

.menu ul li a {
  width: 100 px;
  margin: 0;
  text - align: center;
  padding: 5 px 10 px;
  color: white;
}

.menu ul li a: hover {
  background - color: #737373;
  color: white;
}

.banner {
  position: absolute;
}

.banner > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.banner > .content {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1% 16% 0 16%;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #BABABA;
  text - transform: uppercase;
  line - height: 1.5e m;
}

.button {
  background - color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 1% 16% 0 16%;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}

# submission {
  text - align: center;
}

# secondary - content {
  padding: 60 px 0;
  text - align: center;
}

# secondary - content article {
  width: 460 px;
  height: 270 px;
  float: left;
  background - color: #f5f5f5;
}

# secondary - content article: first - child {
  margin - right: 20 px;
}

# secondary - content article.overlay {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .95);
  height: 230 px;
  width: 190 px;
  padding: 20 px;
}

article h4 {
  border - bottom: 1 px solid #02b8dd;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.more-link {
  border: 1px solid #02b8dd;
  color: #02b8dd;
  padding: 6px 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.more-link:hover {
  background-color: #02b8dd;
  color: #fff;
}

@ media(max - width: 768 px) {}

@ media(max - width: 1024 px) {}
```

Comment: That is a long CSS file, for this post you only need to include the CSS code that relates to your issue. You could also shorten your HTML code in this post to only include the background image and div involved

Comment: in your css you use `# secondary - content` (with whitespace), please be aware that this is not the same as `#secondary-content`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `z-index` to define the order of which element is shown on top (higher value means above an element with a lower value):

```
.header {
    z-index: 1;
}

#secondary-content {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

edit: I assume that your bg.jpg from banner is on top of your secondary content, because it is absolutely positioned, while the content is still static. Absolute positioning means that it doesn't take up the space in the document so other content can move into that space. You should probably read about relative vs. absolute positioning if you don't know what they do exactly.

from https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/:

> The trade-off, and most important thing to remember, about absolute positioning is that these elements are removed from the flow of elements on the page.

Comment: Here, the secondary-content is supposed to start below the background image. Z-index seems to be not working in this case.

Comment: see me edit for an explanation on why I think your background image doesn't make the content move below it

Comment: to fix this you could apply a top margin to your secondary content, but the better way would be to not use absolute positioning for your banner

Comment: Yes,thanks for your help and after setting banner position to absolute and rest all other's position to relative(banner > .content, button, secondary-content(margin-top:46%;)). I could able to see my secondary-content moving down the background image. But, I was expecting to start my secondary-content in a new container(section). I don't want to set the position and margin-top for my every upcoming containers.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achive but I think you should re-think your page structure... take the stackoverflow site as an example: they have the top bar, then the header (with logo and navigation buttons), and below that the content, all relatively positioned. If you want a background image for any of the sections, you should go for `background-image` with `background-size: cover;` (see https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.banner {
  position: relative;
}

.banner > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

should do the trick... ;-)